# Using S3 for User Image Content: Single or multiple buckets?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, saas

What's the best practice for using S3 to store image uploads from users in terms of a single bucket or multiple buckets for different purposes? Use case is a b2b application.

Answer (score 7):

There is no limit to the amount of data you can store in an Amazon S3 bucket. Therefore you could, in theory, simply use one bucket for everything. (However, if you want data in multiple regions, then you would need to use a separate bucket per region.)

To best answer your question, you would need to think about **how data is accessed:**

- If controlling access for **IAM Users**, then giving each user a separate folder is easy for access control using [IAM Policy Elements: Variables and Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)
- If controlling access for **application users**, then users will authenticate to an application, which will determine their access to objects. The application can then generate [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to grant access to specific objects, so separation by bucket/folder is less important
- If the **data is managed by different Admins/Developers** it is a good idea to keep the data in separate buckets to simplify access permissions (eg keeping HR data separate from customer data)

Basically, as long as you have a good reason to separate the data (eg test vs prod, different apps, different admins), then use separate buckets. But, for a single app, it might make better sense to use a single bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's the same in terms of performance and availability. As for splitting content by purpose - It's probably ok to use a single bucket as long as the content is split in different folders (Paths).
We used to have one bucket for user-uploaded content and another one for static (CSS/JS/IMG) files that were auto-generated.